# Serialize Timezone Object

Tags: django

I have a model that has a timezone field using [django-timezone-field](https://www.google.com.co/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXk9yvgK3KAhUG1x4KHVHkDycQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmfogel%2Fdjango-timezone-field&usg=AFQjCNEtQ0fH5Ocx7uatsFHEKVIjy7pMrA&sig2=K3C_UMc6WyVdz-OemE-nHg&bvm=bv.112064104,d.dmo). It stores a pytz object in the field. What I would like to receive back in the response is the object's zone `instance.timezone_field.zone`.

With that field I'm using a ReadOnlyModelViewSet and when issuing a GET request, I get an error `<DstTzInfo 'US/Arizona' LMT-1 day, 16:32:00 STD> is not JSON serializable`.

It makes sense why I'm getting the error, the object is not JSON serializable. But how would I serialize it to use the zone subfield?

To show the structure of the object field, in shell I can get the zone by:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
obj.timezone.zone
"US/Pacific"
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up making a [custom serializer field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) and using the zone field on the timezone object.

```
class TimezoneField(Field):
    "Take the timezone object and make it JSON serializable"
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.zone

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data

class AppSettingsSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    timezone = TimezoneField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserAppSettings
```